# Cleaning Geocode data with r

Tags: r

I am cleaning my dataset and I don't know how to clean GPS data.
when I use the table function I find that they are entered in different shapes.
"547140",
"35.6997",
"251825.7959",
"251470.43",
"54/4077070001",
and "54/305495"

I don't know how to clean this variable with this great difference.
I would be thankful if help me or suggest me a website for training.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which geographic coordinate system the GPS is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is standardizing the GPS by projecting GPS to a coordinate system of choice. Say we have the GPS of amsterdam in two different coordinate systems, one in amersfoort/rd new (espg 28992) and one in wsg1984 (espg 4326):

```
              x            y  location  espg
1: 1.207330e+05 486632.35593 amsterdam 28992
2: 4.884088e+00     52.36651 amsterdam  4326


structure(list(x = c(120733.012428048, 4.88408811380055), y = c(486632.355933105, 
52.3665054922233), location = c("amsterdam", "amsterdam"), espg = c(28992, 
4326)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

What we want to do is reproject our coordinates to one geographic coordinate system of choice. In this case I used WSG1984 (espg 4326).

```
library(sf)

#here I tell R which columns contain the coordinates
coordinates(dt) <- ~x+y

#I now convert the table to a spatial object
dt <- st_as_sf(dt)

#here I split by the different ESPG's present
dt <- split(dt, dt$espg)

#here I loop through every individual espg present in the dataset
for(i in 1:length(dt)){
  #here I say in which coordinate system (espg) the GPS data is in
  st_crs(dt[[i]]) <- unique(dt[[i]]$espg)

  #here I transform the coordinates to another projection (in this case WSG1984, espg 4326)
  dt[[i]] <- dt[[i]] %>% st_transform(4326)
}

#here I bind the items of the list together
dt <- do.call(rbind, dt)

head(dt)
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 4.884088 ymin: 52.36651 xmax: 4.884088 ymax: 52.36651
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
       location  espg                  geometry
4326  amsterdam  4326 POINT (4.884088 52.36651)
28992 amsterdam 28992 POINT (4.884088 52.36651)
```

In the geometry column you now see that the coordinates are equal to one another.

Bottom line is that you need to know the geographic coordinate system the GPS data is in. Then you can convert your data from a table to a spatial object and transform the GPS data to a projection of choice.

In addition, it is always a good idea to check if your assumption on the original ESPG is good by for example plotting the data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)

ggplot(dt) + annotation_mape_tile() + geom_sf(size = 4) + theme(text = element_text(size = 15) + facet_wrap(~espg)
```

In the figurebelow we see that the projection went well for both espg's.

[image: figure]

Comment: many thanks for your detailed explanations @maarvd. I am new to r and my question may seem stupid. i installed sf and geoR packages and try to do what you said. but get this error. could not find function "coordinates<-"

Comment: "coordinates" is from the "sp" package